# What are the document grid settings in inkscape for making an isometric tilemap for tiled?

Tags: tiles, isometric, tiled

I am using inkscape to create a isometric tilemap.  What settings do I need on the grid in document properties in inkscape to make it match up to a 64 x 32 grid in tiled?

Comment: http://www.mbeckler.org/inkscape/isometric_projection/ Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 1):

[As the link that Sidar comment alluded to,](http://www.mbeckler.org/inkscape/isometric_projection/) **in the document properties you have the set both of the angles on the grid to 26.56 degrees.** This will give you a size ratio where the height is half the size of the width.

From there, as long as all the other numbers are in pixel units and set to a value that is in the base 2 set (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc...) you should be able to get set up a grid that matches you're requirements.